# Why do the docs mention that padnone emulates the behavior of built-in map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

In the [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for Python 3.7 and prior, it is mentioned that `padnone` *"emulates the behavior of the built-in map() function"*:

```
def padnone(iterable):
    """Returns the sequence elements and then returns None indefinitely.

    Useful for emulating the behavior of the built-in map() function.
    """
    return chain(iterable, repeat(None))
```

While I understand the usefulness of `padnone`, I do not see how it *emulates* `map` in any way. Is this an error or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that line is outdated - it hasn't been updated for the Python 3 behavior of `map`, or for the existence of `itertools.zip_longest`.

`map` can take a multi-argument function and multiple iterables of arguments:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> list(map(add, [1, 2], [10, 20]))
[11, 22]
```

Back in Python 2, if the iterables weren't all the same length, shorter iterables would be padded with `None`:

```
>>> map(lambda x, y: [x, y], [1, 2], [10]) # Python 2
[[1, 10], [2, None]]
```

but `zip` and `izip` would still stop when the shortest iterable stops:

```
>>> zip([1, 2], [10]) # still Python 2
[(1, 10)]
>>> list(itertools.izip([1, 2], [10])) # still Python 2
[(1, 10)]
```

If you wanted to emulate the None-padding behavior of `map` in your own function that takes multiple iterables, you could extend the shorter iterables with `padnone` before using `zip` or `izip`.

This became less useful with the introduction of `itertools.izip_longest` in Python 2.6, which provides a more convenient, safer way to pad in this use case. With `padnone`, you would have to somehow know up-front which iterables were shorter and needed padding; with `izip_longest`, that was no longer necessary.

In Python 3, `map` no longer `None`-pads by default, so padding isn't really emulating `map` any more.

Comment: I am of that generation which did not use Python2 much, mind you.